# I forgot my apple iPhone 5 iCloud username and password and need help resetting

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, activation-lock

I was in a hospital, and I forgot my apple iPhone 5 username and password and also my iCloud username and password. Can someone help me wipe the phone and get a new iCloud username and password?

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure you can press forgot password on the login screen of iCloud. Enter your email, recieve a link, and change your password.

If you cannot reset the account for any reason, you might need to contact apple support or go to an apple store, prove that you are the owner, and they will wipe it and reset your iCloud username and password.